# Как контролировать скрытые элементы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал метод который скрывает элементы, как можно обойти `checkbox`?

Получается при запуске все элементы скрываются, а мне нужно оставить checkBox в нетронутом состоянии.

```
public void MakeVisible(bool checker)
{
   foreach (Control c in Controls)
   {
     if (checker == true)
     {
        c.Visible = true;
     }
     else
     {
       c.Visible = false;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Вспомните про оператор `is`

Comment: `foreach (Control c in Controls.Where(x=>!(x is CheckBox)))`

Comment: @tym32167, получаю ошибку: `Ошибка CS1061 'Control.ControlCollection" не содержит определения для "Where" и не удалось найти метод расширения "Where", принимающий тип "Control.ControlCollection" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)` . System.Linq добавлен

Comment: `Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x=>!(x is CheckBox))`

Comment: @tym32167, А можно ли задать для определённого CheckBox'a делать обход? просто если на форме несколько CheckBox'ов то они тоже не трогаются.

Comment: `Controls.OfType<Control>().Where(x=>x.Name != "myCheckbox");`